# How to handle records in dataframe with same ID but some different values in columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I am working on a dataframe using pandas with bank (loan) details for customers. There is a problem because some unique loan id have been recorded 2 times with different values for some of the features respectively. I am attaching a screenshot to be more specific.[image]

Now you see for instance this unique Loan ID has been recorded 2 times. I want to drop the second one with nan values but I can't do it manually because there are 4900 similar cases. any idea?

*The problem is not the NaN value, the problem is the double records. I want to drop rows with nan values only for double records not for the entire dataframe*
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count rows where there are > 1, and then only drop nans where there are > 1 rows.

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby(['Loan ID', 'Credit ID'])['Loan ID'].transform('count')
df = df.loc[df['flag'] > 1].dropna(subset=['Credit Score', 'Annual Income']).drop('flag', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I can't use this because there are unique loan IDs which have nan values for these columns and I will drop them among the others

Comment: @Apantazo makes sense, I have updated my answer to accomodate for that.

Comment: thank you very much, I made some little changes and worked properly for my case!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping nan rows, just take the rows where credit score or annual income is not nan:

```
df = df[df['Credit Score'].notna()]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I can't do it this because there are unique IDs recorded once with Credit Score as NaN. The problem is not the NaN value the problem is the double record. I want to drop nan values only for double records.

Comment: @Apantazo try `df.dropna(thresh=2)`